# Kubernetes kubectl apply command does not work, gives connection refused error

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

When I am trying to setup pod network using the following
`kubectl apply -f ./deployment.yaml`

I get this error, please help:

`error: unable to recognize "./deployment.yaml": Get http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused`

Here is the output of the `minikube logs` command:

`command runner: getting ssh client for bootstrapper: Error dialing tcp via ssh client: dial tcp 192.168.64.2:22: connect: operation timed out
  minikube is exiting due to an error. If the above message is not useful, open an issue:
  https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new/choose`

Comment: Can you also add the output of `minikube logs` command. It also maybe possible something wrong happened during the setup, happens a lot with minikube versions from time to time. Try `minikube delete` and `minikube start` again. Also try downgrading minikube version if you are using the latest.

Comment: @RohanMehto I updated my question with the output of the `minikube logs` command

Comment: Your are running minikube on your local machine right?

Comment: This probably is a firewall issue with the hyperv used my your minikube machine. Try using a different vm driver or fix this ones network settings.

Comment: Hi, what do You get from `minikube status` command.

Comment: I installed the latest version of kubectl and it solved the problem. While starting minikube, i was getting a warning saying that my version of kubectl was not compatible with my version of minikube.

Comment: kubectl officially supports cluster one minor version up or down. For basic requests it may work pretty well with even bigger difference. You can check kubectl and cluster versions using `kubectl version`. First line shows you kubectl version info and the second line shows cluster version information for cluster configured in ~/.kube/config  https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/version-skew-policy/

Answer (score 0):

If You are experiencing issues with minikube You can do the following:

As @RohanMehto suggested, check logs with `minikube logs`.

If You see an error which looks starts like this:

```
error: unable to recognize
```

It is usually related to kubectl miss-configuration.

As @emeric mentioned in comments, make sure that Your `kubectl` version supports the version of `minikube`.

Upgrading `kubectl` version to the latest fixed this issue.

Use `minikube status` to check if minikube is properly configured. If there are any errors, this command will provide how to resolve the issues.